# Regex to match 1 or 2 occurrences

Tags: regex, elixir, pcre

I have text with following structure:

> book_name:SoftwareEngineering;author:John;author:Smith;
>   book_name:DesignPatterns;author:Foo;author:Bar;

*Element separator is ;*

*Two author elements could follow book_name element*

*There could be 2 to 10 books*

*One book should have at least one author, but maximum 2 authors*

I would like to extract book_name and individual authors for every book.

I tried regex with `.scan` method (which collects all matches):

```
iex> regex = ~r/book_name:(.+?;)(author:.+?;){1,2}/
iex> text = "book_name:SoftwareEngineering;author:John;author:Smith;book_name:DesignPatterns;author:Foo;author:Bar;"

iex> Regex.scan(regex, text, capture: :all_but_first)
[["SoftwareEngineering;", "author:Smith;"], ["DesignPatterns;", "author:Bar;"]]
```

But it doesn't collect authors correctly. It collects only second author of the book.
Can anybody help with the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part `(author:.+?;){1,2}` of the pattern repeats 1-2 times `author` including what follows up till the semicolon but repeating the capturing group like that will only give you the last capturing group. [This page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) might be helpful.

Instead of using a non greedy quantifier `.*?` you could match not a semicolon repeating a negated character class `[^;]+` that matches not the semicolon.

You might also make use of a capturing group and a backreference for `author`. The name of the book is in capturing group 1, the name of the first author in group 3 and the optional second author in group 4.

```
book_name:([^;]+);(author):([^;]+);(?:\2:([^;]+);)?
```

That will match

- `book_name:` Match literally
- `([^;]+);` Group 1 matching not `;` then match `;`
- `(author):` Group 2 `author`
- `([^;]+);` Group 3 matching not `;` then match `;`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\2:` backreference to what is captured in group 2
  - `([^;]+);` Group 4 matching not `;` then match `;`
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJx908/1/)

Answer (score 2):

In many engines, including Elixir's, you can't repeat multiple capture groups like that and get the result for each repeated group - you'll only get the last result of any given repeated capture group. Rather, write out each possible group individually, and then filter out empty matches:

```
book_name:(.+?;)author:(.+?);(?:author:(.+?);)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/LPgzcG/1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for that, you can use [`String.split/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/3):

```
defmodule Book do
  def extract(text) do
    text
    |> String.split("book_name:", trim: true)
    |> Enum.map(&String.split(&1, [":", ";"], trim: true))
    |> Enum.map(fn [title, _, author1, _, author2] -> {title, author1, author2} end)
  end
end
```

Output:

```
iex> Book.extract(text)
[{"SoftwareEngineering", "John", "Smith"}, {"DesignPatterns", "Foo", "Bar"}]
```

For simplicity I assumed there were always two authors. The last Enum can be replaced with this one, which handles the case where there is no second author too:

```
|> Enum.map(fn
  [title, _, author1] -> {title, author1, nil}
  [title, _, author1, _, author2] -> {title, author1, author2}
end)
```